# Weird behavior when trying to round corners on UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, border

I'm struggling with a weird behavior for hours now with UIView in Swift3. I'm just trying to add a UIView centered inside the screen, with colored and rounded borders.

In order to round the borders easily, I am using the following extension:

```
extension UIView {

 /**
 Rounds the given set of corners to the specified radius

 - parameter corners: Corners to round
 - parameter radius:  Radius to round to
 */
 func round(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
    _round(corners: corners, radius: radius)
 }

 /**
 Rounds the given set of corners to the specified radius with a border

 - parameter corners:     Corners to round
 - parameter radius:      Radius to round to
 - parameter borderColor: The border color
 - parameter borderWidth: The border width
 */
 func round(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat, borderColor: UIColor, borderWidth: CGFloat) {
    let mask = _round(corners: corners, radius: radius)
    addBorder(mask: mask, borderColor: borderColor, borderWidth: borderWidth)
 }

/**
 Fully rounds an autolayout view (e.g. one with no known frame) with the given diameter and border

 - parameter diameter:    The view's diameter
 - parameter borderColor: The border color
 - parameter borderWidth: The border width
 */
 func fullyRound(diameter: CGFloat, borderColor: UIColor, borderWidth: CGFloat) {
    layer.masksToBounds = true
    layer.cornerRadius = diameter / 2
    layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
    layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor;
 }

}

private extension UIView {

 @discardableResult func _round(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat)   -> CAShapeLayer {
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
    let mask = CAShapeLayer()
    mask.path = path.cgPath
    self.layer.mask = mask
    return mask
 }

 func addBorder(mask: CAShapeLayer, borderColor: UIColor, borderWidth: CGFloat) {
    let borderLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    borderLayer.path = mask.path
    borderLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    borderLayer.strokeColor = borderColor.cgColor
    borderLayer.lineWidth = borderWidth
    borderLayer.frame = bounds
    layer.addSublayer(borderLayer)
 }
}

class GameViewController: UIViewController {
 @IBOutlet weak var cardView: UIView!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    cardView.round(corners: UIRectCorner.allCorners, radius: 5.0, borderColor: DesignHelper.defaultColor, borderWidth: 1)
    }
 }
```

I just call myView.round() with the right parameters, but it doesn't work as expected.

1. First, when I just add a UIView in my storyboard, without trying to add borders and color, I have the right behavior. In other words, 
   [my UIView is correctly centered inside the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tXif.png)
2. However, once I try to use the UIView extension and add colored borders, 
   [the view is not correctly centered anymore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSKoR.png). It seems that the space on the right is cropped by something.

My guess is that there is a problem with the bounds or the frame of the mask/layer used to draw the borders. But I didn't find anything to correct that.

Any suggestions?

Comment: at what point in the view lifecycle are you calling `addBorder`? Probably at some time where the layout information is not yet present

Comment: The method addBorder is called by the method round. Normally, when addBorder is called, the mask is already created, as you can see in the code I posted

Comment: check the bounds of your view when round method is called

Comment: Okay, when is `round` called? Basically when is anything of the code you posted called from somewhere inside the actual viewcontroller?

Comment: @ReinierMelian I already checked, the bounds of the UIView is correct when round method is called.

Comment: @luk2302 of course, round method is called in viewDidLoad of my UIViewController

Comment: No, the bound cannot be correct in viewDidLoad, the OS did not lay anything out yet - if the bounds match what they are supposed to, then that is only by coincidence - viewDidLoad is the wrong place to do *anything* with frames, bounds, etc.

Comment: You need to call the round method in your viewWillLayoutSubviews method of your ViewController

Comment: @luk2302 create an Answer with the solution, to avoid this question keep as unAnswered

Comment: Hmm, I moved the call to round method in viewWillLayoutSubviews, but the result is still the same...

Comment: Okay, I finally moved the call to round method in viewDidLayoutSubviews which seem more logical. I guess that at this place, all subviews are loaded so this is the right place to work with bounds, frames...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I was calling the round method in viewDidLoad of my UIViewController. Nevertheless, as @luk2302 noticed, this is not the right place to work with bounds, frames and so on because at this moment, views are not completely loaded.

Therefore, I moved the call to round method inside the method viewDidLayoutSubviews of my UIViewController. That's working fine!